# Why wont siri use wifi?

Tags: siri

Put your iphone in airplane mode and then turn on wifi.

Try to ask siri what one plus one is.

She will fail with the error voice dialing is unavaible during airplane mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem:

[image: 1+1 Siri airplane mode and wifi]

<s>Maybe Siri thinks you're trying to voice dial.</s>

Actually, maybe you don't have Siri on, as voice dialing appears to be enabled by default when you turn Siri Off.

[image: voice dial only]

Comment: I guess when I installed iOS 8 it turned Siri off. Thank you!

Try asking her 0 divided by 0

Comment: It does not work in Spanish :/